# How to change the value of a directives custom property from another directive

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a directive that will set/change a custom property of another directive that lives on the same element.

So, #1 is a 3rd party directive that has a custom @Input property named 'disabled'. I want to create a #2 directive that changes the value of 'disabled' programatically. Is that possible in Angular 8+?

I have tried `@Input() disabled: boolean;` and can read the value but when I try to change the value it doesn't do anything. I have also tried using `@HostBinding() disabled: boolean` but that annotation can only be used on native properties and results in a compile error.

Here is some code using the `@Input`:

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]',
})
export class AppMyDirective implements OnInit {

  // @HostBinding() disabled: boolean; // results in compile error

  @Input() disabled: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // I can read the value just fine
    console.log(`Value of disabled prop: ${this.disabled}`);

    // But changing the value has no effect on the binding
    this.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```
<div appMyDirective someOtherDirective [disabled]="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can access the `appMyDirective` from `someOtherDirective` on the same element by simply injecting `appMyDirective` into `someOtherDirective`'s constructor and call its property.

```
export class SomeOtherDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private myDir: MyDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myDir.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmy2qc?embed=1&file=src/app/two.directive.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Using `@ContentChild` can work in certain circumstances to give direct access to another directive. This worked in my circumstance.

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]',
})
export class AppMyDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  // query for the other directive
  @ContentChild(SomeOtherDirective, { static: false }) someOtherDirective!: SomeOtherDirective;

  constructor() { }

  // @ContentChild isn't available until this lifecycle hook
  ngAfterContentInit() {

    // interact with the other directive directly
    someOtherDirective.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```
<div appMyDirective someOtherDirective [disabled]="false"></div>
```